# What is the easiest way to parse an INI File in C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, ini, fileparse

I'm trying to parse an INI file using C++. Any tips on what is the best way to achieve this? Should I use the Windows API tools for INI file processing (with which I am totally unfamiliar), an open-source solution or attempt to parse it manually?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You can use the Windows API functions, such as [GetPrivateProfileString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getprivateprofilestring) and [GetPrivateProfileInt()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getprivateprofileint).

Comment: GetPrivateProfileInt() and other functions are not recommended by MSDN, because they are obsolete and still provided only for baskward compatibility with older, 16-bit systems.
Instead of that use other approach.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724345(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: They are obsolete because MS doesn't want you to use ini files any more, they are still ideal if you actually want to read or write such files.

Comment: Still work well :)

Answer (score 122):

If you need a cross-platform solution, try Boost's [Program Options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/program_options.html) library.

Comment: i would suggest this library too

Comment: this is the way to go, I don't understand why people just up-vote  not-so-general answer.

Comment: @Gollum, it sounds like Windows is a given dependency. Using the Program Options library means taking on another dependency. Sometimes that's not a big deal, sometimes it is.

Comment: Boost's Program Options seems to use it's own config format, the hash sign (#) is used for comments (instead of semicolon) http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/program_options/overview.html#idp343291568

Comment: @malat Which is why I would recommend [Boost Property Tree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/parsers.html#boost_propertytree.parsers.ini_parser) instead.

Comment: @malat I'm confused, I didn't mention downvoting?

Comment: @sjdowling take a deep breath, re-read the OP answer, then re-read your actual answer, and then guess which INI lib I am now using: Program Options or Property Tree.

Comment: @RamadheerSingh any chance you know if Program Options can be used without exception support?

Comment: He is trying to read an existing INI file, Using boost ist not an answer because it is using an INI like format.

Answer (score 23):

I have never parsed ini files, so I can't be too specific on this issue.
But i have one advice:
**Don't reinvent the wheel as long as an existing one meets your requirements**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file#Accessing_INI_files
http://sdl-cfg.sourceforge.net/
http://sourceforge.net/projects/libini/
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/config-file-parser.aspx

Good luck :)

Answer (score 20):

If you are already using Qt

```
QSettings my_settings("filename.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);
```

Then read a value

```
my_settings.value("GroupName/ValueName", <<DEFAULT_VAL>>).toInt()
```

There are a bunch of other converter that convert your INI values into both standard types and Qt types. See Qt documentation on QSettings for more information.

Comment: Not bad, although if you make changes they save them back to the .ini file without really telling you (i.e. the destructor calls `sync()`, which can be a surprise) and that destroys the comments and order in which variables were defined previously...

Comment: QSettings is also case sensitive, some SomKeyName and somekeyname are not the sames.  Some bad design decisions in this module.

Answer (score 16):

I use [SimpleIni](https://github.com/brofield/simpleini). It's cross-platform.

Comment: SimpleIni is now hosted in Github.

Comment: It appears to support Visual Studio and GCC, MIT license. As of the time of writing, its automated builds are failing, last release was in Sept. of 2013, last commit: June 2020

Answer (score 8):

this question is a bit old, but I will post my answer. I have tested various INI classes (you can see them on my [website](http://www.24hsoftware.com/DevelopersForum/CrossPlatform-C-Library.html#comment-1400)) and I also use simpleIni because I want to work with INI files on both windows and winCE.
Window's GetPrivateProfileString() works only with the registry on winCE.

It is very easy to read with simpleIni. Here is an example:

```
#include "SimpleIni\SimpleIni.h"    
CSimpleIniA ini;
ini.SetUnicode();
ini.LoadFile(FileName);
const char * pVal = ini.GetValue(section, entry, DefaultStr);
```

Answer (score 6):

[inih](https://code.google.com/p/inih/) is a simple ini parser written in C, it comes with a C++ wrapper too. Example usage:

```
#include "INIReader.h"    

INIReader reader("test.ini");

std::cout << "version="
          << reader.GetInteger("protocol", "version", -1) << ", name="
          << reader.Get("user", "name", "UNKNOWN") << ", active="
          << reader.GetBoolean("user", "active", true) << "\n";
```

The author has also a list of existing libraries [here](http://blog.brush.co.nz/2009/02/inih/).

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried [libconfig](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/); very JSON-like syntax. I prefer it over XML configuration files.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up using inipp which is not mentioned in this thread.

https://github.com/mcmtroffaes/inipp

Was a MIT licensed header only implementation which was simple enough to add to a project and 4 lines to use.

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in platform portability, you can also try Boost.PropertyTree. It supports ini as persistancy format, though the property tree my be 1 level deep only.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you plan on making the app cross-platform, using the Windows API calls would be the best way to go. Just ignore the note in the API documentation about being provided only for 16-bit app compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is very old, but I came upon it because I needed something cross platform for linux, win32... I wrote the function below, it is a single function that can parse INI files, hopefully others will find it useful.

rules & caveats: 
buf to parse must be a NULL terminated string. Load your ini file into a char array string and call this function to parse it.
section names must have [] brackets around them, such as this [MySection], also values and sections must begin on a line without leading spaces. It will parse files with Windows \r\n or with Linux \n line endings. Comments should use # or // and begin at the top of the file, no comments should be mixed with INI entry data. Quotes and ticks are trimmed from both ends of the return string. Spaces are only trimmed if they are outside of the quote. Strings are not required to have quotes, and whitespaces are trimmed if quotes are missing. You can also extract numbers or other data, for example if you have a float just perform a atof(ret) on the ret buffer.

```
//  -----note: no escape is nessesary for inner quotes or ticks-----
//  -----------------------------example----------------------------
//  [Entry2]
//  Alignment   = 1
//  LightLvl=128
//  Library     = 5555
//  StrValA =  Inner "quoted" or 'quoted' strings are ok to use
//  StrValB =  "This a "quoted" or 'quoted' String Value"
//  StrValC =  'This a "tick" or 'tick' String Value'
//  StrValD =  "Missing quote at end will still work
//  StrValE =  This is another "quote" example
//  StrValF =  "  Spaces inside the quote are preserved "
//  StrValG =  This works too and spaces are trimmed away
//  StrValH =
//  ----------------------------------------------------------------
//12oClocker super lean and mean INI file parser (with section support)
//set section to 0 to disable section support
//returns TRUE if we were able to extract a string into ret value
//NextSection is a char* pointer, will be set to zero if no next section is found
//will be set to pointer of next section if it was found.
//use it like this... char* NextSection = 0;  GrabIniValue(X,X,X,X,X,&NextSection);
//buf is data to parse, ret is the user supplied return buffer
BOOL GrabIniValue(char* buf, const char* section, const char* valname, char* ret, int retbuflen, char** NextSection)
{
    if(!buf){*ret=0; return FALSE;}

    char* s = buf; //search starts at "s" pointer
    char* e = 0;   //end of section pointer

    //find section
    if(section)
    {
        int L = strlen(section);
        SearchAgain1:
        s = strstr(s,section); if(!s){*ret=0; return FALSE;}    //find section
        if(s > buf && (*(s-1))!='\n'){s+=L; goto SearchAgain1;} //section must be at begining of a line!
        s+=L;                                                   //found section, skip past section name
        while(*s!='\n'){s++;} s++;                              //spin until next line, s is now begining of section data
        e = strstr(s,"\n[");                                    //find begining of next section or end of file
        if(e){*e=0;}                                            //if we found begining of next section, null the \n so we don't search past section
        if(NextSection)                                         //user passed in a NextSection pointer
        { if(e){*NextSection=(e+1);}else{*NextSection=0;} }     //set pointer to next section
    }

    //restore char at end of section, ret=empty_string, return FALSE
    #define RESTORE_E     if(e){*e='\n';}
    #define SAFE_RETURN   RESTORE_E;  (*ret)=0;  return FALSE

    //find valname
    int L = strlen(valname);
    SearchAgain2:
    s = strstr(s,valname); if(!s){SAFE_RETURN;}             //find valname
    if(s > buf && (*(s-1))!='\n'){s+=L; goto SearchAgain2;} //valname must be at begining of a line!
    s+=L;                                                   //found valname match, skip past it
    while(*s==' ' || *s == '\t'){s++;}                      //skip spaces and tabs
    if(!(*s)){SAFE_RETURN;}                                 //if NULL encounted do safe return
    if(*s != '='){goto SearchAgain2;}                       //no equal sign found after valname, search again
    s++;                                                    //skip past the equal sign
    while(*s==' '  || *s=='\t'){s++;}                       //skip spaces and tabs
    while(*s=='\"' || *s=='\''){s++;}                       //skip past quotes and ticks
    if(!(*s)){SAFE_RETURN;}                                 //if NULL encounted do safe return
    char* E = s;                                            //s is now the begining of the valname data
    while(*E!='\r' && *E!='\n' && *E!=0){E++;} E--;         //find end of line or end of string, then backup 1 char
    while(E > s && (*E==' ' || *E=='\t')){E--;}             //move backwards past spaces and tabs
    while(E > s && (*E=='\"' || *E=='\'')){E--;}            //move backwards past quotes and ticks
    L = E-s+1;                                              //length of string to extract NOT including NULL
    if(L<1 || L+1 > retbuflen){SAFE_RETURN;}                //empty string or buffer size too small
    strncpy(ret,s,L);                                       //copy the string
    ret[L]=0;                                               //null last char on return buffer
    RESTORE_E;
    return TRUE;

    #undef RESTORE_E
    #undef SAFE_RETURN
}
```

How to use... example....

```
char sFileData[] = "[MySection]\r\n"
"MyValue1 = 123\r\n"
"MyValue2 = 456\r\n"
"MyValue3 = 789\r\n"
"\r\n"
"[MySection]\r\n"
"MyValue1 = Hello1\r\n"
"MyValue2 = Hello2\r\n"
"MyValue3 = Hello3\r\n"
"\r\n";
char str[256];
char* sSec = sFileData;
char secName[] = "[MySection]"; //we support sections with same name
while(sSec)//while we have a valid sNextSec
{
    //print values of the sections
    char* next=0;//in case we dont have any sucessful grabs
    if(GrabIniValue(sSec,secName,"MyValue1",str,sizeof(str),&next)) { printf("MyValue1 = [%s]\n",str); }
    if(GrabIniValue(sSec,secName,"MyValue2",str,sizeof(str),0))     { printf("MyValue2 = [%s]\n",str); }
    if(GrabIniValue(sSec,secName,"MyValue3",str,sizeof(str),0))     { printf("MyValue3 = [%s]\n",str); }
    printf("\n");
    sSec = next; //parse next section, next will be null if no more sections to parse
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a late answer..But, worth knowing options..If you need a cross-platform solution , definitely you can try GLIB,, its interesting.. (https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Key-value-file-parser.html)