# Using ini-files with VB 6.0

Tags: vb6

I must be getting daft, but I can't seem to find how to read old-fashioned ini files with VB 6.0. All I can seem to find is about reading from and writing to the registry. Can someone push me in the right direction? Mind you, I am not a programmer, just a hobbyist trying to have some harmless fun with his computer, so please don't be to harsh when you point out the bleedin' obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the top answer on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-parse-an-ini-file-in-c). Nope, it's no different in VB! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use the GetPrivateProfile* functions. Some examples of how to do this with a Declare statement are here:

- [codeguru](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-201546.html)
- [vbforums](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=439267)

Comment: +1 Also Karl E Peterson's drop-in class is good http://vb.mvps.org/samples/kpIni/