# VB6 categorize search function

Tags: vb6

If I have a text file that contains the below information, what is the best way to search for the version, for example on system1 only? (in vb6 code, can I use `InStr`?)

```
[system1]

version=xx
date=xx


[system2]

version=xx
date=xx
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/165796/11683.

Answer (score 1):

The sample file looks like a standard INI file. You can read these using the [`GetPrivateProfileString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms724353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and related functions. You can also enumerate the sections and values using [`GetPrivateProfileSectionNames()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724352%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`GetPrivateProfileSection()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724348%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: +1 Also Karl E Peterson's drop-in class is good http://vb.mvps.org/samples/kpIni/

Answer (score 0):

Supposing there is a space after the version and before date (str would be your text):

```
Dim version As String
version = Mid(str, InStr(str, "version") + 8)
version = Mid(version, 1, InStr(version, " "))
```

But there are a bunch of functions to parse .ini files out there.

Comment: what if i only want the version under [system2]..yours will find the first occurrence of 'version' wont it?

Comment: You can find the second index of version or find system2 first.

Comment: @HanletEscaño but it may not by in the second `[SystemX]` group.

Answer (score 0):

I created a text file `"C:\MYFILE.TXT"` and this is the content of the file:

```
[system1]

version=aa
date=bb


[system2]

version=yy
date=zz

[system3]

date=4

[system4]

[system5]
```

As you can see, I made all possible situation, ie. a system with version info, a system with no version info, etc. Then I wrote this code:

Here is one way to look for a value under a categorized list:

```
Dim mySystem As String
Dim myVersion As String

mySystem = "[system2]"    'Replace this with the system you are looking for

Dim strTmp As String
Dim SystemFound As Boolean
Dim VersionFound As Boolean

Open "c:\myfilename.txt" For Input As #1
    Do While Not EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, strTmp
        If InStr(UCase(strTmp), UCase(mySystem)) > 0 Then
            SystemFound = True
            strTmp = ""
            Do While Not EOF(1) And InStr(strTmp, "[") = 0
                Line Input #1, strTmp
                If InStr(UCase(strTmp), "VERSION") > 0 Then
                    VersionFound = True
                    myVersion = Mid(strTmp, InStr(strTmp, "=") + 1, Len(strTmp))

                End If
            Loop
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
Close #1

If SystemFound And VersionFound Then
    MsgBox "The Version of " & mySystem & " is " & myVersion
ElseIf SystemFound And Not VersionFound Then
    MsgBox "The system " & mySystem & " has no version definition"
ElseIf SystemFound = False Then
    MsgBox "The system " & mySystem & " is not found in file"
End If
```