# Read var in config file

Tags: c++

This is the file that I need to read.

```
id=1    
Name=test
Path=/var/www
```

I can read this file like this:

```
std::ifstream f("/home/atmoner/conf.ini");
std::string s;
```

But how do I read the var `Path` with c++?

Comment: If it's an INI file, may be it can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-parse-an-ini-file-in-c

Comment: usualy INI file have header in square bracket: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file

Comment: @ibrohimislam it's for windows -_-

Comment: I mean Boost's Program_options.

Comment: The [fstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream) class template has  the necessary facilities.

Comment: Read line by line, split at "=" sign, put the two resulting strings into a map as key and value, look up Path in the map. Would be one simple way to address the issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Boost option](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/program_options/overview.html#idp435878016):

```
std::string path;
boost::program_options::variables_map vm;
boost::program_options::options_description desc(
    "Allowed options");

desc.add_options()
    ("Path", boost::program_options::value<std::string>(&path), "document here...");

// boost::program_options::store(boost::program_options::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
boost::program_options::store(boost::program_options::parse_config_file<char>("a.ini", desc), vm);
notify(vm);

//now variable path will contain the value.
```

[Fplus option](https://github.com/Dobiasd/FunctionalPlus/)

```
string line = "Path=/var/www";
std::vector<std::string> vs = fplus::split('=', false, line);
string key = vs[0];
string value = vs[1];
```

Hand written:

```
std::string s="Path=/var/www";
string::iterator it = std::find(s.begin(), s.end(), '=');
if(it!=s.end())
{
    std::string key(s.begin(), it);
    std::string value(it+1, s.end());
}
```